# Is there a way to save drafts of posts?

Tags: support

I frequently start a question or answer, but get interrupted by other things.

Does anyone know if there is a way to save a post as a draft (obviously, other than to start writing it somewhere else and save it there)?

If not, is that a feature that SE could enable, or we could request to be put in to some future build?

Comment: Chrome/Firefox/Safari have a neat extension called "Lazarus" that will save a draft for any web form. http://getlazarus.com/download

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

Typically as you type content for a question or an answer, it will [auto-save a draft periodically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/271012).

You may need to wait up 45 seconds if you want to capture *everything* you've typed since the last auto-save.

Comment: Apparently you can use **Ctrl+S** in Firefox to manually save your draft as well.